# Android Database in Physical Device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have Created Database in SQLite Database in Android...and I have debug this app in my Physical Android device.

I want to get that Database file from device.
How can I get??

Comment: Google *android get sqlite database from device*

Comment: Agreed with @RoyFalk - looks like a duplicate to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access in Your device,

/data/data/{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}/databases/{YOUR_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME}.sqlite

It will be there.

edit))

maybe although you don't have root access, using ADB Shell

in Command Prompt,

```
adb shell 
cp /data/data/{YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME}/databases/{YOUR_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME}.sqlite/sdcard/{YOUR_SQLITE_DATABASE_NAME}.sqlite
```

is work. (maybe path is wrong by device)